# Why do elliptical copula densities contain $x_1$ and $x_2$, but Archimedean copula densities contain $u_1$ and $u_2$?

Tags: probability, independence, copula, marginal-distribution, bivariate

$$c\left(u_{1}, u_{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho_{12}^{2}}} \exp \left\{-\frac{\rho_{12}^{2}\left(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}\right)-2 \rho_{12} x_{1} x_{2}}{2\left(1-\rho_{12}^{2}\right)}\right\}$$

is the **copula density** of the Gaussian copula, which is an **elliptical copula**, where $\rho_{12}$ is the parameter of the copula, $x_{1}=\Phi^{-1}\left(u_{1}\right), x_{2}=$ $\Phi^{-1}\left(u_{2}\right)$ and $\Phi^{-1}(\cdot)$ is the inverse of the standard univariate Gaussian distribution function.

$$
c\left(u_{1}, u_{2}\right)=\left(1+\delta_{12}\right)\left(u_{1} \cdot u_{2}\right)^{-1-\delta_{12}} \times\left(u_{1}^{-\delta_{12}}+u_{2}^{-\delta_{12}}-1\right)^{-1 / \delta_{12}-2}
$$
is the **copula density** of the Clayton copula, which is an **Archimedean copula**,
where $0<\delta_{12}<\infty$ is a parameter controlling the dependence. Perfect dependence is obtained when $\delta_{12} \rightarrow \infty,$ while $\delta_{12} \rightarrow 0$ implies independence.

#### Question

As you can see, both are functions of $u_1$ and $u_2$, but the elliptical copula density has the actual random variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ on the right hand-side, whereas the Archimedean copula densities actually have what we would expect from the function on the RHS: $u_1$ and $u_2$. This property seems to be a shared between all elliptical versus Archimedean copula densities. Why?

> Source of formulas: Aas et al 2009 "Pair-copula constructions of multiple dependence"

Comment: thanks. but Archimedeans don't have $\Phi^{-1}(u_1)$, they have $u_1$ directly

Comment: separate question maybe you can help with: if the marginal vector $u_1$ is uniformly distributed  (summing to 1?) and is a random variable, what is its expected value $\mathbb{E}(u_1)$? Any rules about this, like it being 0.5, as opposed to the case where we always know $\mathbb{E}(x_1)\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yeah so it sums to 1

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly the reason why I thought up 0.5, which means the mean of a marginal, despite the marginal being a random variable, has a constant mean for any underlying dataset $x$

Comment: I know because it's constant for whatever data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copulas are distribution functions with marginals having support in $[0,1]$. It has become customary to assume in addition that the marginals are Uniform rv's (but this is not necessary).

So one could use Copulas without digging deeper into the $u$-variables.

But it is the case that we mostly use Copulas to model dependence between random variables that have arbitrary marginals. In this case, we invoke the probability integral transform and we view $u$ as being the distribution function of some rv $X$, $U = F_X(X),\;\;u = F_X(x)$, treated as an rv itself.

Notation wise, it is not good practice to use $x$ to denote e.g. $\Phi^{-1}(F_x(x))$, because it may confuse. It is better to use some additional symbol, say something like

$$u_1 \equiv F_x(x_1),\;\;\; x^*_1 \equiv  \Phi^{-1}(u_1)$$
As for how Archimedean Copulas are constructed, here is a snippet from Nelsen's book to get you started:

[image]

$C(u,v)$ is a Copula, and Copulas constructed like that are called "Archimedean".

Comment: thanks for the review of what copulas are, but the question is about Archimedeans vs elliptical copula densities. Like what was being asked about the shown formulas and a comment, Archimedeans don't have $\phi^{−1}(u_1)$, they have $u_1$ directly, whereas elliptical copulas don't have have $u_1$, but $\phi^{−1}(u_1)$. This is what I don't understand why there's a difference between them

Comment: No, that's a different question than the one you asked in your post. Anyway, this is just a different way to construct Copulas, one through inverse distribution functions and one through generator functions. We use the inverse distribution functions in elliptical Copulas to, exactly, obtain a Copula that is elliptical.

Comment: your post makes absolutely no mention of Archimedeans. so "We use the inverse distribution functions in elliptical Copulas to, exactly, obtain a Copula that is elliptical", whereas we *do not use* the inverse distribution functions in the case of *Archimedean* copulas?

Comment: @develarist Indeed we don't. See e.g. Nelsen's book on Copulas ch. 3, or any other relevant resource, on how Archimedean Copulas are constructed.

Comment: Ok so that's the answer I was looking for. I will look there, but maybe you could explain it even better than Nelson, it's up to you. Actually, that one is not available anywhere near where I am and there is no pdf copy

Comment: Marginals don’t have to be uniform? What about the probability integral transform?

Comment: @Dave No they don't, in the sense that the Copula function will still be a distribution function, even if the marginals are not Uniform, as long as they range in $(0,1)$. This can be realized if one reads carefully Nelsen and how the Copula function is defined. But it is true that it has become a universal convention to define Copula as a distribution function with Uniform marginals.

Comment: But if the marginals aren’t uniform, is it still “the rest” of a joint distribution?

Comment: @Dave I don't understand what do you mean by "the rest".

Comment: There are the marginal distributions. Then there is the dependence structure, which I am considering “the rest” of the joint distribution.

Comment: @Dave. Then yes. As I said, the Copula with non-Uniform marginals (but still ranging in $(0,1)$) has all the properties of a multivariate distribution function. Again, if you read Nelsen as suggested previously, you will realize that. It is another matter as to where such a construction could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$c\left(u_{1}, u_{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho_{12}^{2}}} \exp \left\{-\frac{\rho_{12}^{2}\left(\Phi^{-1}(u_{1})^{2}+\Phi^{-1}(u_{2})^{2}\right)-2 \rho_{12} \Phi^{-1}(u_{1}) \Phi^{-1}(u_{2})}{2\left(1-\rho_{12}^{2}\right)}\right\}$$
the Gaussian copula is also a function of $(u_1,u_2)$ and only of $(u_1,u_2)$. The use of $(x_1,x_2)$ makes the formula more condensed, but obviously less clear. Copulas share the property that they define a joint distribution such that both marginals (in $u_1$ and $u_2$) are uniform $\mathcal U(0,1)$, while creating a different type of dependence between the two components. The Gaussian copula describes the dependence through the intuitive correlation between Gaussian variates.

Comment: thanks, but why don't Archimedeans have $\phi^{−1}(u_1)$ in their copula density formula, while elliptical copulas do? To me $\phi^{−1}(u_1) \neq u_1$